# How to store newly added element in a variable using jquery?

Tags: jquery

When I console newNode it still print parent, why?

```js
function appendNewStage() {
  var parent = $('.ci-journey-interactions-canvas_row');
  var newStage = `<ul class="ci-journey-interactions-canvas__journey-list 
                    stage">
                  <li>
                    <span class="ci-journey-interactions-box__droppable-
                     element ci-droppable"></span>
                  </li>
                </ul>`;
  var newNode = $(parent).append(newStage);
  console.log(newNode.html());
}
appendNewStage()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ci-journey-interactions-canvas_row"></div>
```

Comment: `parent` is already a jQuery object. You can simply do: `var newNode = parent.append(newStage)`. This is also why there is a convention of using `$var` for jQuery objects, so you won't end up confusing yourself: `var $parent = $(...)`, then you can use `var $newNode = $parent.append(newStage)`

Comment: I created a snippet. I do not see the issue?

Comment: If you use `var $parent = $('.ci-journey-interactions-canvas_row');`, then you know you do not need to wrap in $() later

Comment: What's the problem?  according to that snippet is working well

Comment: It's because `append()` returns the original parent element, not the content which was added to the DOM.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Yea.. how to fix it ??

Comment: Invert the append action: `var $newNode = $(newStage).appendTo(parent);` although note that `$newNode` will only be available within the scope of your function

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yeaa. It works fine! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
var newNode = $(newStage).appendTo(".ci-journey-interactions-canvas_row");
```

Answer (score 0):

dont need to make a parent a object use it directly

```
function appendNewStage(){
var parent = $('.ci-journey-interactions-canvas_row');
var newStage = `<ul class="ci-journey-interactions-canvas__journey-list 
                stage">
              <li>
                <span class="ci-journey-interactions-box__droppable-
                 element ci-droppable"></span>
              </li>
            </ul>`;
var newNode = parent.append(newStage);
 console.log(newNode);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The original code works well. Click the button in the snippet to add a new stage

```js
function appendNewStage() {
  var parent = $('.ci-journey-interactions-canvas_row');
  var newStage = `<ul class="ci-journey-interactions-canvas__journey-list 
                    stage">
                  <li>
                    <span class="ci-journey-interactions-box__droppable-
                     element ci-droppable"></span>
                  </li>
                </ul>`;
  var newNode = $(parent).append(newStage);
  console.log(newNode.html());
}
appendNewStage()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="appendNewStage()">add a new stage </button>

<div class="ci-journey-interactions-canvas_row"></div>
```

Comment: Yea it's working, but my problem is I want to store newly added element in a variable because it should be droppable. How to fix that?

Comment: It was put into the variable `newNode`, wasn't it?. You can see that the output of  `console.log(newNode.html());` is becoming longer and longer if you click the `add new` button repeatedly.

Comment: `It was put into the variable newNode, wasn't it?` No, as `append()` returns the parent element, not the appended content.

Comment: the appended content was stored in `newStage`. if all `newStage`s should be stored, then a global variable is needed or use cookie or localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

The last element of `.ci-journey-interactions-canvas_row` is the appended element . Maybe you can use the `newNode` variable globally so you can use this in other functions.

```
var newNode = null;

function appendNewStage() {
  var parent = $('.ci-journey-interactions-canvas_row');
  var newStage = `<ul class="ci-journey-interactions-canvas__journey-list 
                    stage">
                  <li>
                    <span class="ci-journey-interactions-box__droppable-
                     element ci-droppable"></span>
                  </li>
                </ul>`;
  $(parent).append(newStage);
  newNode = $(parent).find('ul:last-child').parent().html();
}
```